# NullPointer when launching a FragmentActivity with a List?

Tags: android

I keep getting a NullPointer when trying to launch a FragmentActivity.

Here is the nullpointer im getting.

```
09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409):     at com.fttech.youtubeReaults.searchYoutube(youtubeReaults.java:182)
09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409):     at com.fttech.youtubeReaults.onActivityCreated(youtubeReaults.java:59)
09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:760)
09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:933)
09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:578)
09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1219)
```

09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:380)
    09-05 14:44:21.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19409):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

The NullPointer is pointing me here..

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state){
    super.onActivityCreated(state);

    search = AccessibleYouTube_Fragment.search;

    ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewSearchResultTitle))
            .setText("Captioned search results for " + search);
            //NullPointer is pointing me to this line
    ArrayList<YouTubeResult> ytResults = searchYoutube(search);
```

Is it something i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone is null in your code and you try to acess it.....

On Nullpointer I have just suggest u that .......................

System.out.println("search " + search);..

.and print AccessibleYouTube_Fragment.search,also textview there were something is null.................